# f-noelide-constructors is not working as expected

Tags: c++

I have following the program.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class t> class myclass
{
    private:
        t x;
        t y;

    public:
        myclass(t a, t b);
        t get_max();
 };

template<class t> myclass<t>::myclass(t a, t b)
{
    x = a;
    y = b;
}

template<class t> t myclass<t>::get_max()
{
    if(x > y)
         return x;
    else
        return y;
 }

int main()
{
    myclass<int> obj = myclass<int>(2, 3);
    cout << "max : " << obj.get_max() << endl;
}
```

I explicitly called myclass obj = myclass(2, 3) instead of myclass obj(2, 3) to see the compilation failure because of below reasons

```
1) I defined one constructor which will take 2 parameters and there is no default constructor which will take 0 parameters.
2) I compiled with f-noelide-constructors which shouldn't do any optimization related to constructors.
```

In this case, an object should be created with the default constructor and the object should be copy constructed with myclass(2, 3) and compiler is not able to see default constructor, compilation should fail. But the program is running fine. Could any one please let me know is there any reason why default constructor is not getting called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myclass<int> obj = myclass<int>(2, 3);
```

On this line, `myclass<int>` is move-constructed from a temporary `myclass<int>`, using the automatically-generated move constructor.

You can see that this is happening by deliberately preventing the compiler from generating the move constructor, by putting a line such as

```
myclass(myclass&&) = delete;
```

in the `myclass` definition, and observing the resulting error.

But at no point does this require `myclass` to be default constructed -- the temporary on the right-hand side is constructed using the two-argument constructor, and the move construction happens in one step after that -- using the move (or copy) constructor like this is not the same as default constructing `obj` followed by copy/move assignment.

EDIT: The above applies to C++11 and 14. If you're using an earlier version of C++, `obj` will be copy constructed rather than move constructed, but the same applies -- at no point does the default constructor need to be called.

In C++17, [guaranteed copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) means that `obj` will be constructed as if you had said `myclass<int> obj(2, 3)` directly, i.e. `-fno-elide-constructors` will have no effect. (Thanks to Guillaume Racicot for the reminder.)

Comment: As per my understanding, move constructor will come in to picture if I use -std=c++11.

Comment: @kadina note that in c++17, `myclass<int> obj = myclass<int>(2, 3)` is guaranteed to be the same as `myclass<int> obj{2, 3}` so now it's no longer an optimization, but a requirement.